# Where did the South Dublin/"D4" accent come from?

Tags: england, ireland

I've lived in Ireland for a decade in Dublin and outside Co. Dublin. I've noticed that many of the accents sound similar with the exception of the South Dublin accent. It sounds entirely different from the rest of accents in Dublin and around the country.

I read somewhere that the accent was influenced by English settlers during the English occupation of Ireland when Dublin was known as 'the Pale'.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: What is not covered in _[Wikipedia:D4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dublin_4)_?  "A change in accent occurred between those born roughly before 1970 and those born in the early 1970s or later." (Additional explanation and citations on Wikipedia)

Answer (score 2):

**Upper-middle class**

The Dublin D4 post code area is best described as Upper-middle class.

[Independent ie](https://www.independent.ie/opinion/analysis/how-dublin-4-turned-into-dublin-forlorn-26556988.html)

> This week, the Dublin Horse Show has brought much-needed gaiety to an area that is going through troubled times. Dublin 4, the pulsing heart of Boomtown Ireland and the only Irish post code that became a term of derision, will never be poverty-stricken.

> The diplomats and lawyers who inhabit its tree-lined avenues will always ensure that it remains a by-word of affluence, but there is no doubt it has lost some of its lustre.

**D4 accent**

According to Professor Dolan speaking to the Independent ie, this is an accent which originated in the D4 post code area in response to trying to get away from perceived poverty and failure.

[Independent ie](https://www.independent.ie/irish-news/d4-accent-is-loike-totally-over-claims-ucd-linguist-29654140.html#:%7E:text=The%20D4%20accent%20may%20have,now%20encountered%20around%20the%20country.)

> The D4 accent may have originated in the fashionable Dublin 4 postal district, however, it is now encountered around the country.

> Borrowing from Home Counties British English and American English, it is distinctive for its distorted vowels, so that "car park" becomes "corpork", a liberal dousing of the quotative "like" or "loike" and what is known as the high-rising terminal whereby statements sound like questions.

> "People who use it want to get away from Irish culture as much as possible because they associate it with poverty and failure. They are trying to sound like the Home Counties," he said.

**Recent change**

Raymond Hickey has written a book on this very subject and according to Raymond this change in accent is rapid and recent.

[Dublin English, by Raymond Hickey](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=AmpOAwl3KzcC&pg=PA45&redir_esc=y)

> The rapid change of Dublin English is seen as a correlate to the many social and economic developments which have occurred in recent years.

[image: Dublin English by Raymond Hickey]

**Where did the South Dublin/“D4” accent come from?**

It comes from the Dublin D4 post code area. According to professors and book writers it is a recent phenomenon and does not appear directly connected to "the pale".

Comment: So he's saying its beyond the pale?